# Build and Deploy using TeamCity for DEV/UAT/LIVE

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to setup TeamCity to build/deploy the site to DEV/UAT. I am not able to get or dont know how to set up TeamCity to build and deploy to remote servers after commit to a certain branch. So basically we have three branches in GIT DEV/Staging/Master and I want TeamCity to trigger build and deploy after commit to each branch separately. So if user commit/merge to dev branch then TeamCity should build and deploy to dev server and if user commit/merge to staging branch then it should build/deploy to UAT.

Is this even possible? If yes then please let me know how?

Thanks

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

I believe your build server is separate from your deploy server. You can try 2 approaches

1. Have teamcity agents running on the deployed servers. Create artefacts in the build process and download these artefacts using the agents in the deploy steps
2. In case you want all your agents to run on the same server as Teamcity, Have a SSH (or similar ) functionality copy over your build artefats onto the deploy box.